# Create a LinearSegmentedColormap with values within range

Tags: matplotlib, colormap

I have several grids that I want to draw in a `matplotlib` gridspec image. Each image will have a color map and I want to make that colormap interpretable for all images.
For that I need to create a general colormap that will be applied to all images. The values range should be between the min of all images values and the max of all images values.

Therefore, I need to create a `LinearSegmentedColormap` where I can define the max and the min.

Is it possible to define the values that represent the spectrum of the colormap?

Example:

1 - The three values are (from left to right) : -2.024131 , -3.837179 ,-2.947026

[image]

2 - -2.343214, -4.110780, -1.029205

[image]

The first color of 1 is white while in 2 the color is red, although the values are very close. What is happening is that the color is calculated within the three values from each image, making it impossible to compare both images - the scale is different.

What I want is to create a general colormap and then the values from each image are retrieved from the global range.

Kind regards

Comment: Can't you create a LinearSegmentedColormap green-red-white for 0-1-2, then translate each triple into 0-1-2 values in ascending order? vmin-vmax does not ensure that your middle value will be in the red range.

Answer (score 0):

If you really need one comon colormap, you could create a [`BoundaryNorm`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.colors.BoundaryNorm.html) with bounds exactly in the middle between the color values:

```py
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import matplotlib as mpl

def min_val(combinations, color):
    return min([x for xs, cs in combinations for x, c in zip(xs, cs) if c == color])

def max_val(combinations, color):
    return max([x for xs, cs in combinations for x, c in zip(xs, cs) if c == color])

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(6, 1))
fig.subplots_adjust(bottom=0.5)

colors = ['grey', 'red', 'white']  # ordered from lowest to highest
combinations = [[[-2.024131, -3.837179, -2.947026], ['white', 'grey', 'red']],
                [[-2.343214, -4.110780, -1.029205], ['red', 'grey', 'white']]]
bounds = [min_val(combinations, 'grey'),
          (max_val(combinations, 'grey') + min_val(combinations, 'red')) / 2,
          (max_val(combinations, 'red') + min_val(combinations, 'white')) / 2,
          max_val(combinations, 'white')]

cmap = mpl.colors.ListedColormap(colors)
norm = mpl.colors.BoundaryNorm(bounds, len(colors))
cbar = mpl.colorbar.ColorbarBase(ax, cmap=cmap,
                                 norm=norm,
                                 orientation='horizontal')
cbar.set_label("Boundary norm")
fig.show()
```

[image: resulting colorbar]

An alternative approach combines a `LinearSegmentedColormap` and a [`TwoSlopeNorm`](https://matplotlib.org/devdocs/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.colors.TwoSlopeNorm.html):

```
colors = ['grey', 'red', 'white']  # ordered from lowest to highest
combinations = [[[-2.024131, -3.837179, -2.947026], ['white', 'grey', 'red']],
                [[-2.343214, -4.110780, -1.029205], ['red', 'grey', 'white']]]
bounds = [(min_val(combinations, c) + max_val(combinations, c)) / 2 for c in colors]

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(6, 1))
fig.subplots_adjust(bottom=0.5)
cmap = mpl.colors.LinearSegmentedColormap.from_list('segmented', colors)
norm = mpl.colors.TwoSlopeNorm(vcenter=bounds[1], vmin=bounds[0], vmax=bounds[2])
cbar = mpl.colorbar.ColorbarBase(ax, cmap=cmap,
                                 norm=norm,
                                 orientation='horizontal')
cbar.set_label("TwoSlopeNorm")
fig.show()
```

[image: twoslopenorm]

Comment: I thought about this but with that approach I would reduce my range of values to x colors, losing information. The idea was to keep the spectrum of colors of a cmap and make it common for all images

Comment: Is this TwoSlopeNorm closer to what you were looking for? If not, could you edit your question and add more details?